# MySQL JSON_TABLE to get both key and value from a dictionary/hash as rows

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have a JSON data

```
{"1": 7, "2": 7, "3": 7, "4": 7, "5": 7, "6": 7, "7": 7, "8": 5, "9": 7, "10": 5, "11": 0, "12": 6, "13": 0, "14": 7, "15": 4, "16": 0, "21": 7, "22": 7, "23": 7, "24": 7, "25": 0, "26": 7, "27": 4, "28": 0, "29": 0, "30": 2, "31": 0, "32": 0, "41": 6, "42": 0, "43": 0, "44": 0, "45": 5, "46": 4, "47": 6, "48": 0, "61": 0, "62": 0, "63": 7, "64": 7, "65": 4, "66": 0, "67": 0, "68": 3, "69": 0, "70": 0, "71": 0, "72": 7, "73": 0, "74": 0, "75": 0, "76": 0}
```

I want to get rows `t1(k INT, v INT)`

I can get either keys:

```
SELECT k FROM `tbl`, 
JSON_TABLE(json_keys(json_data), '$[*]'
           COLUMNS(
               k  INT PATH '$'
           )
) AS jsk;
```

OR values:

```
SELECT v FROM `tb`, 
JSON_TABLE(json_data, '$.*'
           COLUMNS(
               V  INT PATH '$'
           )
) AS jsv
```

---

How can I get both in a single query?

Comment: The solution in the linked answer should work for you if you just get rid of the `WHERE` condition at the end.